# Use variants of an elastic dashboard (stage,prod..)

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, dashboard

I have a kibana dashboard for a stage environment that shows multiple visuals with queries that all filter for "kubernetes.namespace:stage".

I now have to add another dashboard for prod where I filter for "kubernetes.namespace:prod". Both dashboards use the same datasource. I could just duplicate the dashboard and edit the filter but are there easier ways? Like using a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't duplicate the dashboard but rather use [controls](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/add-controls.html) to select the `kubernetes.namespaces` value you want to see at the time.

I would do it this way so you'd only have to maintain 1 dashboard and not duplicate changes every time you make them.

The controls is a 8.9 feature but there are similar methods in previous versions.